# Setting FTP to passive mode by default in php.ini

Tags: php, configuration, ftp

After a server change, it seems all PHP scripts which use FTP need to be modified as follows:

```
$conn = ftp_connect("host.com");    
ftp_login($conn,"user", "pass");     

//must add this:
ftp_pasv($conn, true);
```

Is there a simple way to mimic this call to `ftp_pasv` through `php.ini` (or some other config file).

It would be easier than modifying each script.

Answer (score 2):

No, it cannot be changed. The passive mode is unconditionally off initially. In other words, the FTP always defaults to the active mode.

Check the [`ftp.c` file](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/ftp/ftp.c) in PHP repository.

The [`ftpbuf.pasv` field](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/0103d1e3bc7b3861a2bff81de204eceb3f4c212a/ext/ftp/ftp.h#L71) is only ever set to non-zero in the [`ftp_pasv` function](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/0103d1e3bc7b3861a2bff81de204eceb3f4c212a/ext/ftp/ftp.c#L831).

It has been like this ever since the [passive mode support was added in PHP 4](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/0413f524800e8830e2fdb161b61284a039504545).

---

Alternative solutions:

- There's APD PHP PECL package (not maintained currently) that may allow you do override the `ftp_connect` function to call the `ftp_pasv`.
- Revert the server change, what likely involved sealing the active FTP mode ports in the server firewall.